# Take ONLY ObjectAce if exists and ignore ClassAce

Tags: symfony, acl

after some hours of research in the Symfony code and in the web, I decided to ask here.

Let's get started:

I have an entity which has an **ObjectAce** and a **ClassAce** assigned, where the **ClassAce** has the **VIEW** attribute set, but the **ObjectAce** **not**.

My goal is that the AclVoter denies access to the entity if the **ObjectAce** has **no VIEW** attribute, **no matter** what is set on the **ClassAce**.

Seems like this is not the default behavior of Symfony's ACL system, but I also fail to find a way to make it possible.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

At the end, I decided to create a custom [security voter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters_data_permission.html). 
This security voter acts only if the incoming object is an [object identity](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Acl/Domain/ObjectIdentity.html) which targets a [class scope](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl_advanced.html#scope-of-access-control-entries). If the [security identity](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Acl/Domain/UserSecurityIdentity.html) has no class access to the desired resource, but has access to one or more objects of that class type, the voter grants access as it would when the security identity would have class access. On any other request, the voter abstains.

Its more or less a virtual class access, but still only for specific domain objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a custom [Security Voter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters_data_permission.html) which will implement the behavior you desire.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I already did so. I'll update my question.